# Python seperate numbers where no obvious seperation symbol is vissible

Tags: python, list

I have a text file that I am trying to turn into something I can do math operations with.

The issue with the file is that some numbers are not seperated correctly like the following:

`mylist = ['21', '0', '0-2.0000000000000E-001-6.0000000000000E+001']`

Right now I have everything as a string and want to convert it to a float but before doing so I need seperate the last three numbers to get the following output:

`mylist = ['21', '0', '0' , '-2.0000000000000E-001' , '-6.0000000000000E+001']`

I need something that seperates the item in the list when a minus sign is present, except when the minus sign is preceded by E.

Comment: If the text file is that screwed up, then how do you know that the `21` at the start is not a `2` followed by a `1`?  What you're asking for is not possible in general, it's only possible for your specific example because the non-separated numbers happened to be negative.

Comment: I know because the numbers are seperated by spaces in the original document except when there is a negative sign in front then it simply skips the space. Just adding a space in front of all negative signs would be easy but then it ruins the scientific notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be checked against a few more examples, but a regular expression can do the trick:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> findall(r'[\+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:E[\+\-]\d+)?', ' '.join(mylist))
['21', '0', '0', '-2.0000000000000E-001', '-6.0000000000000E+001']
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working with my large file